# probability Let the cube, on the sides of which the numbers from 1 to 6 are written, be arranged so that with random tossing (random tossing)

Tags: probability

Let the cube, on the sides of which the numbers from 1 to 6 are written, be arranged
so that with random tossing (random tossing)
the number 3 falls 5 times more often than the rest. The cube is tossed
(tossing the dice) two times. Let D be obtained by subtracting the result
second toss from the result of the first toss. What kind
values ​​can take the value D and with what probability
(probability)?

Comment: how to start the probability of 3 is 1/6 is five-time more means 5/6? than what to do?

Comment: Hi Mohammad--What have you tried?  https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how to start the probability of 3 is 1/6 is five-time more means 5/6? than what to do?

Comment: Do you mean that it's not a regular dice, but a loaded one ? (Still with the different numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6$ ?

Comment: The cube in question that you are tossing is an *unfair die* and is unfairly weighted so that the result of $3$ comes up more often than it would in a fair die.  I read this problem as saying that the number $3$ occurs with probability $p$ and each other number occurs with probability $q$ such that the number $3$ comes up five times more likely than each other number, i.e. $p=5q$, and you have the sum of probabilities should be $1$ as usual implying $p+q+q+q+q+q=1$

Comment: This should be plenty of information to find the probability $p$ and further to find the probability $q$.  From there, you should be able to continue the problem as normal via product rule and careful observation.

Comment: i did not understand what is D actually?

Comment: The result of subtracting the second die from the first...  as the problem statement says...  so, if we were to toss the die twice we take the value shown on the first die and we take the value shown on the second die... then we subtract the second value from the first.  So, for instance if the first die shows a $3$ and the second die shows a $1$ the value of $D$ in this instance would be $3-1=2$.  On the other hand if the first die showed a $2$ and the second die showed a $4$ then $D$ would be $2-4=-2$.  It is a random variable, like all other random variables.

Comment: it can take -5 to 5 also in between total 36 number but what will be the probability as 3 occurs more

Comment: is the probability to get 0 is 5/6 and rest 1/6

Comment: There are $36$ pairs of results of dice rolls.  Many of those result in the same value for $D$ however, so there are fewer possibilities for $D$.  The extremes are, as you correctly note $-5$ and $5$ (*resulting from $1-6$ and $6-1$ respectively*).  The probability of having gotten $0$ corresponds to the having rolled two $3$'s or having rolled a not-$3$ followed by the same number, and using the notation I used above occurs then with probability $p^2+(1-p)q$... not $\frac{5}{6}$.  Further, "*the rest 1/6*", no... if you added up all of the probabilities that would give you larger than $1$

Comment: The formulation "random tossing (random tossing)" is confusing. Why did you use the formulation again in paranthesis ?